# insertNewObject seque to detailViewController with newManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Up in viewDidLoad I have:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
```

For the insertNewObjectMethod I have:

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    CommodityTypes *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    self.detailViewController.detailItem = newManagedObject;
    self.detailViewController.context = context;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showCommodityTypesDetail" sender:sender];

}
```

There is also:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showCommodityTypesDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        CommodityTypes *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext;
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setContext:context];
    }
}
```

When I build & run the app and select the + button it does the segue to the detail page, but does not load the newManagedObject information.

My guess is that performSegueWithIdentifier triggers a call to prepareForSeque, and because there is no selected row nothing gets loaded, but this method overrides the earlier         self.detailViewController.detailItem = newManagedObject;
        self.detailViewController.context = context;

How do I work around this?
First guess, insertNewObject creates newManagedObject. How do I select the row that it appears on in the table?

Beginning iOS programmer here.

**Eureka**
`self.detailViewController` is the detail view controller *instance* used by the iPad split view controller **not** the detail view controller *instance* used by the *iPhone* interface.

`performSegueWithIdentifier` *does* send a message to `prepareForSegue`. To fix my problem I had to do two things.

Create a second segue from the master view controller to the detail view controller.
The original seque was linked from the table view row to the detail view controller. The second segue I linked from the master view controller to the detail view controller. (Use the view controller icon in the footer of the view controller in Interface Builder.)

Move the object creation lines from `insertNewObject` to `prepareForSeque` in an if statement that selects for the unique name of the second seque.

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ctAddButtonToDetail" sender:sender];

}
```

and

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ctMasterRowToDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        CommodityTypes *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext;
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setContext:context];
    }

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ctAddButtonToDetail"]) {

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
        CommodityTypes *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:newManagedObject];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setContext:context];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your insertNewObject: method, you have these two lines -

```
self.detailViewController.detailItem = newManagedObject;
self.detailViewController.context = context;
```

...which suggest that you've already tried to initialise the detailViewController which you're going to segue to. You don't need to do that, it's initialised automatically because you've linked up in the storyboard, and you pass it any information you want to in the prepareForSegue:sender: method - in the way you're doing it in fact.

As to getting the right data, maybe you could do that in your tableView's delegate method, tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, and just set an ivar to the row number of the selected row so you can get the info in the prepareForSegue: method.

Comment: My problem is that there is no selected row. I'm selecting the + button in the navigation bar. I want that to segue directly to the details view instead of having to manually select the new row after selecting it.

Comment: In which case your request for data using NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; is surely not relevant either? Which must mean that you can prepare the data in the prepareForSegue anyway.

Comment: Eureka!  `self.detailViewController` is the view controller _instance_ that the iPad split view uses. It is **not** the view controller instance that is being segued to in the iPhone interface.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing the object to the destination view controller.  You don't need to give the context too... that can be obtained from the object itself (all NSManagedObjects have a managedObjectContext property).

It looks like you are passing the information.  I don't know what you mean about the selected part.

On the view controller that is being sequed-to, you need to make sure you grab the data being passed in... viewDidLoad is the most common place.